# How To Dynamically Truncate The Y-Axis Title On Chart Resize/Reflow In Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Highcharts Chart in a resizable div. Is there any way to get the Y-Axis Title to be responsive?

Try out in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3DXRlGkBlGoRdwxjP1rG?p=preview

I have used these options, but the width (height when rotated) of the title seems to not change at all:

```
chart: {
  reflow: true
},
yAxis: [{
  title: {
    text: "Really really long Y-Axis Title. aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa",
    style: {
      width: "100%",
      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
      textOverflow: "ellipsis"
    }
  }
}]
```

};

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width of the text when you first load the chart, then set the width again on resize.

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function () {
      this.yAxis.map((axis) => {
        axis.update({
          title: {
            style: {
              width: this.plotHeight
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

`plotHeight` is the height of the chart plotting area, which I used for the maximum width of the axis title.

If you're using version 5.0.7+, you can maybe use the [render event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render), which fires on chart load and on each redraw. I'm still on version 4.x so I had to use the [load](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) event with another event of my own (in my case, an event triggered by a jQuery click)

if you need the ellipses, you can extend Highcharts with a [plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) to update the text value after the title has been rendered by hooking into the `buildText` function on the `SvgRenderer` prototype:

```
(function (H) {

  H.wrap(H.SVGRenderer.prototype, 'buildText', customBuildTextFunc);

  function customBuildTextFunc(proceed, wrapper) {

    // original function
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    var yAxisClass = 'highcharts-yaxis-title';

    var isYAxisTitle = wrapper.textStr 
      && wrapper.element 
      && wrapper.element.classList 
      && wrapper.element.classList[0] === yAxisClass;

    if (isYAxisTitle) {

      var $container = $('<div></div>').append(wrapper.element.innerHTML);

      var $tspans = $container.find('tspan');

      var $first = $tspans.eq(0);

      $first.append('...');

      $container.empty().append($first);

      wrapper.element.innerHTML = $container.html();
    }
  }

}(Highcharts));
```

I had issues with `getSVG()` when I used proper ellipses (…), so I just used three full stops (my ellipses were rendered as a box .. wrong encoding or something, I guess).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [responsive.rules](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules) to set the text's width depending on a chart's height.

With the options like below, the width of the text will be `100%` if the chart's height is below `300`  and `400%` otherwise.

```
yAxis: [{
  title: {
    text: "Really really long Y-Axis Labelllllllll. Really really long Y-Axis Labelllllllll. Really really long Y-Axis Labelllllllll",
    style: {
      width: "400%",
      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
      textOverflow: "ellipsis"
    }

  }
}],
responsive: {
  rules: [{
    condition: {
      maxHeight: 300
    },
    chartOptions: {
      yAxis: {
        title: {
        style: {
           width: '100%'
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
},
```

example: http://plnkr.co/edit/h852BIAdPo3lCIesFmBT?p=preview

Responsive rules were added in Highcharts 5, so if you want to use older version, @FlorianHeer answer does the work.

Comment: An upvote for showing me that responsive option. I'm stuck for now with 4.x but will certainly be trialing the update soon!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that is a bit of a strange behaviour, I would expect all parts to be reevaluated. But as the resulting Graph is an SVG, I guess some elements are forgotten in a reflow.
You could force a complete recalculation of spaces and sizes after resizing your containing div:

```
$("#outer").height(498).width(498);
c0.yAxis[0].setTitle({ 
    text: 'Really really long Y-Axis Labelllllllll. Really really long Y-Axis Labelllllllll. Really really long Y-Axis Labelllllllll',
    style: {
        width: $('#outer').height()-100,
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
        textOverflow: "ellipsis"
    }}, true);
c0.reflow();
```

Comment: Hi, I understand how the width changes to perceived height, and that is what I meant. See in the example where it is the truncation of the text that is the issue to be resolved. Setting the width to 400% doesn't fix it when the chart is shrunk.

Comment: Completely changed my answer. Sorry, apparently I didn't get the issue before.

Comment: Thanks, this seems promising. Any way that Reflow call can be avoided if a chart's Reflow option is set to true? Also, like redraw, is there any event that can be watched when the chart reflows?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I just keep hacking at highcharts, especially as I have to deal with a 4-version.